# The F16 stick movement is little. But how?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, f-16, sidestick

The F16 stick movement is very little, is 1/8inch. So there is just a stop point at the end of the movement, or the stick is  hard all the time, but move  a bit ? There is increase in stiffness to apply  full displacing of the stick?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer (would like to know myself), but given that the F-16 stick senses the force rather than movement, it doesn't matter too much. The movement, whatever it is, is just for the pilot, i.e. ergonomics.